# Is this avro message valid?

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I have some example Avro messages from a kafka provider that looks to start as such:

```
00000000  4f 62 6a 01 04 16 61 76  72 6f 2e 73 63 68 65 6d  |Obj...avro.schem|
00000010  61 ef bf bd 24 7b 22 74  79 70 65 22 3a 22 72 65  |a...${"type":"re|
```

That `ef bf bd 24` I expected to be the length of the schema which is 2332 bytes. I'm having trouble confirming that the zigzag varint (why would a length, which can never be negative, be zigzaged?) is the right value. I take it to be somewhere in the 200K range.

I believe that's why I'm having trouble using the avro-tools jar on it at all to either getmeta, getschema or transform to json.

Is this a particular known issue with either the version of Avro Tools which is 1.8.2 or the platform Mac OS with java 1.8.0_102-b14 for that tool version?

Does this look like it's been mis-encoded? Because all calls to use the tools give me:

```
$ java -jar ~/Downloads/avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson dt20170607hr08_1496793109907_11_8229967.bin.1
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:288)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:112)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.<init>(DataFileStream.java:84)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileReadTool.run(DataFileReadTool.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

Comment: did you figure out what was wrong? facing a similar issue here

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan No, what ended up happening was that I asked the people generating the avro to double check everything, and we deleted these files, and modified the schema, started again, and then things worked more as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a single record in the Avro file.  The system generating the Avro file is running the older version.  I have a similar issue with Nifi running 1.7.7.  By merging two records into the Avro file, we were able to work around the issue.

Avro 1.8.2 fixes the bug.

1.7.7 and 1.8.0/1.8.1 all have the single record issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1888